# CentOS NFS server session crashes

Tags: linux, centos6

I recently received some alerts that 2 of my backups failed to an NFS mount in my environment. After reviewing the logs I realized that the software was unable to establish a connection to the NFS mount in order to verify enough storage was availabe to run the job. I ssh'd into the box from the server that was experiencing the issue, thus verifying connectivity to the remote destination, and after reviewing df -h to find that there was plenty of storage, I then decided to "browse" that storage, and this is when my sessions continuously crash. Everytime I try to browse the /home/export/ path, the TTY session freezes and I have to establish a new session. Has anyone seen this? I'd tell you the version of CentOS that i'm running and some other versioning info, but I just rebooted the NFS mount and can't login at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

Kill any NFS server daemons on the server, and any nfs-related processes on the client, and restart on both ends. In my years of working as a sysadmin, I've seen NFS freeze time and time again. It's one of the frustrating/unstable things about it.

Comment: This is a fix but does not prevent the problem, what errors do you get? The tty is freezing because it's waiting to change into a directory that does not exist. Do you have errors in your event logs? What are your mount options? Do you know that the mount target was available the entire time (is it a client, network or server problem)?  NFS does not "just crash", when configured properly on good hardware it's an extremely reliable protocol.

Comment: Keeping your system updated is the key to fixing these type of problems.

Comment: not with NFS it isn't :)  "reliable" and "NFS" don't go together. network file locking in general is problematic, right? NFS simply reflects that fact more readily, than, say AFS